# Django - URL and namespace

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django template in the Book app and using URL tag to redirect to the Account app's URLs. But it says `account' is not a registered namespace`.

**book.urls:**

```
app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account'))
]
```

**book.views:**

```
class HomePageView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'book/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_books'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

**templates/book/home.html:**

```
<div id="register">
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'account:register' %}"> Sign Up </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**account/urls:**

```
app_name='account'
urlpatterns=(
    path('register/', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('successful/', views.successful_created, name='successful'),
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem which you are facing is mostly because you are trying to define `account` app from `book` app. What you need to do is

In the main project `urls.py` which is in the same directory as `settings.py` add both **book** and **account** app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^book/', include('book.urls', namespace="book")),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', namespace="account")),
]
```

And now your **book.urls** will look:

```
app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

**account/urls** will look:

```
app_name='account'
urlpatterns=(
    path('register/', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('successful/', views.successful_created, name='successful'),
)
```

Comment: @Jinx Glad I could help. You should upvote and accept the answer then. :)

Comment: Its something which many new contributors are unaware of what to do when they receive a correct answer. Hence during initial days most of the new contributors are made aware about what to do and how to do.

Comment: haha it's ok. I used to try to upvote when I was under 15 reputation, but I wasn't able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you remove namespace = account and just use path('account/', include('account.urls') it'll work fine.

Comment: I tried, it won't work that way. That's why I added namespace='account'.

Comment: look below is my own configuration and it works :
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1.0/', include('api.urls')),
]